# Unit Problem in Designing a Filter for a Given Auto Correlation Function

Tags: filters, filter-design, autocorrelation

Given a WSS process with the following Auto Correlation Function:

$$ r\left ( \tau \right ) = {\sigma}^{2} {e}^{-\alpha \left | \tau \right |} $$

The Laplace Transform would be:

$$ R \left ( s \right ) = \mathfrak{L} \left \{ r \left ( \tau \right ) \right \} = \frac{-2 \alpha {\sigma} ^ {2}}{\left ( s - \alpha \right ) \left ( s + \alpha \right )} $$

Hence the filter would be of the form:

$$ H \left( s \right) = \frac{c}{s + \alpha} $$

My question is about units.
In the Auto Correlation Function the units of $ \alpha $ are [Hz].
While in the filter form, assuming $ s = j \omega $ the units are [Rad / Sec].
How this conflict can be resolved?
What a I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Radians are considered to be dimensionless.  See [Are angles dimensionless?](https://web.archive.org/web/20171224103431/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/64034.html) and [Dimensionless quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity).  They are considered to be pure numbers like $\pi$.

So $\alpha$ is in Hz, which is a measure of 1/second, and $s$ is also considered to be measured per second.